# Android Studio 3.2 ERROR resource linking failed Style.xml problem

Tags: android, gradle, resources, styles

This is the output errors mostly errors are linked with my /values --> /style.xml
I cannot figure out how to solve this error i have uninstalled android studio and again download it but the error repeats it self HELP!!!! NEED !!!

```
Output:  warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_action_bar_home_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_action_bar_up_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_action_menu_overflow_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_action_mode_done without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_activitychooserview_choose_application without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_capital_off without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_capital_on without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_alt_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_ctrl_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_delete_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_enter_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_function_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_meta_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_shift_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_space_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_menu_sym_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_prepend_shortcut_label without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_search_hint without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_searchview_description_clear without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_searchview_description_query without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_searchview_description_search without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_searchview_description_submit without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_searchview_description_voice without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_shareactionprovider_share_with without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/abc_toolbar_collapse_description without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/search_menu_title without required default value.
warn: removing resource com.example.ahsan.tree:string/status_bar_notification_info_overflow without required default value.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) not found.
```

These are the Commands for errors that are mostly style.xml

```
    C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:9: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimary (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/colorPrimary)' not found.
C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:10: error: style attribute 'attr/colorPrimaryDark (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/colorPrimaryDark)' not found.
C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:11: error: style attribute 'attr/colorAccent (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/colorAccent)' not found.
error: resource style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize) not found.
error: resource style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.FixedSize) not found.
error: resource style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle.Common) not found.
C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:4: error: style attribute 'attr/barLength (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/barLength)' not found.
C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:5: error: style attribute 'attr/gapBetweenBars (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/gapBetweenBars)' not found.
C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-hdpi-v4\values-hdpi-v4.xml:6: error: style attribute 'attr/drawableSize (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:attr/drawableSize)' not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.MinWidth) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge) not found.
error: resource style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar (aka com.example.ahsan.tree:style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar) not found.
error: failed linking references.

Command: C:\Users\Ahsan\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\fff13b5cf61430cfb7ed93349534cd31\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe link -I\
        C:\Users\Ahsan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar\
        --manifest\

        C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml\
        -o\
        C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\processed_res\debug\processDebugResources\out\resources-debug.ap_\
        -R\
        @C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\intermediates\incremental\processDebugResources\resources-list-for-resources-debug.ap_.txt\
        --auto-add-overlay\
        --java\
        C:\Users\Ahsan\AndroidStudioProjects\tree\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\processDebugResources\r\
        --custom-package\
        com.example.ahsan.tree\
        -0\
        apk\
        --no-version-vectors
```

This is the daemon error

```
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
```

Images

[Style.xml image of error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sukCM.png)

[Build.gradle (Module:app) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Tp29.png)

[Build.gradle (Project:app_name) image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/metVz.png)

[Main Activity Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iQx0.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's mostly coming from your styles & values. How about : `Theme.AppCompat` instead of : `style/Theme.AppCompat` and the rest the same without `style/`.. Also, in values, `colorPrimary` instead of `attr/colorPrimary`. Give it a try and let us know.

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>

THIS IS MY CURRENT STYLE .XML

Comment: Would you add the styles or relevant codes to your question? Use the edit button

Comment: i have modiefied it to some extent

Comment: Can I see your `build.gradle` dependencies?

Comment: uploaded it in description

Comment: You're `MainActivity` has error(s). Your styles looks fine so far. How about checking MainActivity errors? However, if it was because of `R` import, do a clean project or rebuild project or remove the R import and then try to import it back.

Comment: I have uploaded Main Activity image you can check it @Mohsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import the `R` import. Maybe that causes the issue.

Place your mouse in the `MainActivity` and it will suggest to add `R` import, use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> and import the `R`.

Then do rebuild project from `Build`.

Comment: IT GIVING ME OPTIONS LIKE:
1) Create Test
2) Create subclass
3) Add JavaDoc
4) Make package-private

Comment: So it’s more complicated than that. Have you tried reinvalidate-cashes restart?! From ‘File’ on Android Studio? Then check to see if you can import the R or not.

Comment: Any Clue Importing didn't helped?

Comment: Yeah i tried reinvalidate cashes restart it did nothing

Comment: Haven't you tried creating a new project? This is pretty weird and rare issue which you're facing. Try creating a new project and then see if it has the same issue or not.

Comment: I created new user in my window 10 and installed android studio in it its working with no error now but what's the solution to that problem ... i have made count less new project but the error remains

Comment: I’m guessing that there were few problems with the app which it couldn’t download or get the right packages. If it’s working with the new user, I suggest you should move your codes to the new working project. Like I said, this is pretty rare and weird issue since it could be fixed by the approaches I’ve told in my answer.

Comment: i appreciate your response and will transfer my projects . Thanks for your help i think so too that their was something wrong with installation process

Answer (score 1):

Recently i got this issue. what i did mistake is putted the xml header twice by mistake like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="#41ba7a" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#f9f9f9" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

Hop it will help you.

Comment: Yeah, that was my case. Thanks you man. Copy and past is the evil.)

Comment: @A.Kazarovets if my answer is helpful then give upvote it will help many people.thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this;

File --> Project Structure --> app(inside Modules) --> Dependencies -- Click "+" --> Library dependency --> Search "appcompat" and click "com.android.support:appcompat-v7(com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1)" --> click OK.

This should solve your error!

Check this link. You can see at 1:35.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRLfzi5bdJs

Answer (score -1):

change the compileSdkVersion > 28